# {Symbol(@@lockerLiveValue) : undefined} when passing list between lightning web components

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-web-security

When passing a list from a parent to child component in LWC, I am getting errors when trying to access the list from within the child component.

For example, pass a list containing just an ID ['id1'] to a child component. Try to access the list in the dev console from the child component, and the following error is printed:

> WARNING: Unsupported id1 method: Symbol(@@lockerNearMembrane). Returning undefined

The list is printed as:

> Proxy {Symbol(@@lockerLiveValue): undefined}

JSON stringifying/parsing the list will bring it back to the expected values.

This is causing severe lag as the list becomes more complex, with each element containing objects rendered in a datatable (even JSON stringifying/parsing is very slow). Any thoughts as to what is causing this?

Comment: Are you in Locker Service or Lightning Web Security? Have you tried switching security modes to see if that makes a difference?

Comment: Good point - it doesn't happen with LWS turned on.

Comment: The main problem is that the situation is situational. Passing data from parent to child to grandchild can cause this, and the solution may be to copy the data at each level, but the downside to this is can break reactivity. As such, if you can provide some code code, that might be helpful for further diagnoses.